# React - использование классов вместо хуков

Tags: javascript, reactjs, классы, hook, react-hook

Здравствуйте уважаемые читатели, мой вопрос заключается в том что можно ли использовать классы в React вместо хуков в 2020, является ли такой подход нормальным? Кроме этого, настанет ли время когда официально уберут классы или все будут использовать только хуки

Comment: а почему такой подход не должен быть нормальным?

Comment: [TLDR: There are no plans to remove classes from React.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#gradual-adoption-strategy)

Comment: А почему такой подход должен быть нормальным? Как всегда, я задаю вопрос а меня вопросом отвечают, спасибо

Comment: Чтобы предположить, что такой подход не должен быть нормальным, нужны какие-то предпосылки. Из вопроса не ясно, почему ты решил, что такой подход, вдруг, должен стать не нормальным. Вопрос про будущее - слишком широк, так как неизвестно что решат, например через месяц, или через год. А через 10 лет может и реакта не будет, что в принципе может означать, что официально убрали не только классы, но и хуки.

Comment: Решение на данный момент указано по ссылке в комментарии выше ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Да я уже видел спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые проблемы можно решить только классом. Например, [отлов ошибок в компоненте](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch). Однако, я бы настоятельно рекомендовал перейти на хуки, так как это просто и невероятно экономит время на отладке, чтении чужого кода...

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Example "componentStack":
    //   in ComponentThatThrows (created by App)
    //   in ErrorBoundary (created by App)
    //   in div (created by App)
    //   in App
    logComponentStackToMyService(info.componentStack);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Comment: а как этот ответ связан с вопросом?

Comment: @Grundy некоторые проблемы можно решить только классом и поэтому никуда они не денутся, да, ответ связан с вопросом

Comment: во-первых, _пока_ можно решить только классом, во-вторых, вопрос-то: является ли такой подход нормальным и не уберут ли классы. А в ответе - что что-то можно сделать только классом, причем неизвестно - нужно ли.